# Rails deployment workflow: Test locally a production bugfix before pushing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, production-environment

I'm missing something here.

I just fixed a bug on the production state of my app. When I merge it to my development state, it works very well (locally and remotely).

But I really don't know how to get my local machine to my production state, since the db state has changed since then.

Which means I'm about to push to staging a modif I haven't even tested locally.

What's the best practice in this situation?

- To have multiple local db states by creating more local environments?
- To rollback my db to the previous state? (How?)
- To reset my local environment accordingly?
- To "save" the db state when push to staging/prod to be able to restore when in this situation?
- Anything else?

Feels like this should be routine for every app manager, but I really can't see how to deal with this, and find rails migrations not so handy at the moment...

Thanks

Comment: I assume that by "database state" you mean "state of database structure", not "state of database data"?

Comment: Yes, that's right! I figured my way out by running the staging environmnent locally, though I'm still unsure this is a rails best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your local database to the same *structure* as what you have in production:

First get a local checkout of the branch or tag that's deployed to production.

```
rake db:test:prepare
rake test # or rake spec
```

That should clean out your test database, and then recreate it according to your db/schema.rb, which should be the same schema you have in prod. Assuming that you first wrote a failing test, then fixed the bug and watched the test pass, your tests should now be passing.

Comment: So it means you'd use the test environment to make the local debugging?

Comment: Yes, I'd use the test environment at the very least. By creating an automated test for the bug that fails until it's fixed, you prove that you can reproduce the bug reliably, that your fix works, and that the same thing won't break again in the future. If you also wanted to do it in the dev environment, you could also reset your dev database on that branch, but you would lose any records you had set up in dev. Up to you whether that's worth it in your situation. Suppose you could back up first, revert dev db, test, then go back to master branch and restore dev db from backup.